# All differences in Harakaat of words in Hafs vs. Shu’bah

Tags: qiraat, mushaf

Salam, so I was wondering if anyone has a list of all different spelling, not actually the rules themself, just the different spelling. If not, does anyone have a online Mushaf for Shu’bah?

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://live.islamweb.net/quran_list/shuaba/quran.pdf)'s a moshaf bi riwayat Sho'abah 'an 'Assim شعبة عن عاصم and [here](https://www.noor-book.com/%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%87-%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B9%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%85-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%87-pdf) you can download a document about the osol of this qira'a, which should guide you to the major differences between Sho'abah and Hafs 'an 'Asim.

As for the differences the list might get too long as the recitation differences are far more than 500, here just a few general examples (general application and some differences from surat al-Baqara in special- to not confuse you I will put the reading of Sho'aba in bold letters):

- Where ever Hafs reads هُزُوًا (like in [2:67](http://legacy.quran.com/2/67), [2:231](http://legacy.quran.com/2/231) ...),Sho'bah follows the readings of al-Hijaz reading it **هُزُؤًا** with hamza on the waaw. The same applies for **كُفُؤًا** vs. كُفُوًا in surat al-Ikhlas, one could say  Sho'bah followed the Hijazi readings when it comes to hamza's at the end of words which are not pronounced in Hafs like reading **زكرياء** instead of زكريا.
- Where ever Hafs reads خُطُوات (like in [2:168](http://legacy.quran.com/2/168), [2:208](http://legacy.quran.com/2/208) ...), Sho'bah follows the readings of al-Hijaz reading it **خُطْوات** with sukun on the ta'.
- Sho'abah reads the plural of البُيُوت or بُيُوت (as read in Hafs like in [7:74](http://legacy.quran.com/7/74), [24:61](http://legacy.quran.com/24/61), [33:34](http://legacy.quran.com/33/34) ...) with a kasra on the baa' **بِيُوت**.
- Except with verse ([5:16](http://legacy.quran.com/5/16)) Shoa'bah read رِضْوان (as in Hafs) **رُضْوان** with a damah on the raa'.
- Shoa'bah reads the singular المَيِّت or مَيِّت (asa read in Hafs in verses like [3:27](http://legacy.quran.com/3/27), [7:57](http://legacy.quran.com/7/57)) **مَيْت** without shiddah and with sukun on the ya' instead of a kasra.
- Shoa'bah read instead of مُبَيِّنَة singular or مُبَيِّنَات plural (with a kasra on the yaa' as done by Hafs in [4:19](http://legacy.quran.com/4/19) and [24:34](http://legacy.quran.com/24/34)) with a fatha on the ya' **مُبَيَّنَة / مُبَيَّنَات**.
- Where ever Hafs reads الغُيُوب (like in [5:109](http://legacy.quran.com/5/109)), Sho'aba has replaces the damah on the ghayn with a kasra reading it **الغِيُوب**.
- When ever Hafs reads مَّعِيَ (like in verse [21:24](http://legacy.quran.com/21/24)), Sho'aba takes away (leaves out) the fathahj from the yaa' reading it **مَّعِي**.
- Except with ([11:42](http://legacy.quran.com/11/42)) Sho'aba reads (in modern Arabic يابني) يَبُنَيَّ -according to rasm al-moshaf- as in Hafs (like in [31:16](http://legacy.quran.com/31/16), [31:17](http://legacy.quran.com/31/17) ...), **يَبُنَيِّ** with a kasra on the yaa' instead.
- When ever Hafs reads وَعُيِونٍ -with a damah on the 'ayn- (like [15:45](http://legacy.quran.com/15/45)), Sho'aba replaces the damah with a kasra and reads it **وَعِيِونٍ**.
- Where ever Hafs reads نُّكْرا (like in [18:74](http://legacy.quran.com/18/74) and [18:87](http://legacy.quran.com/18/87)), SHo'aba replaces the sukun on the kaaf with a damah reading it **نُّكُرًا**.
- Sho'aba removed (or left out) the first hamza on the waaw from اللُّؤْلُؤْ and لٌؤْلُؤًا as read by Hafs (see verses such as [52:24](http://legacy.quran.com/52/24) ,[55:22](http://legacy.quran.com/55/22), [76:19](http://legacy.quran.com/76/19) ...) and read it **لٌوْلُؤًا** and **اللُّوْلُؤْ** instead.
- Where ever Hafs reads إنْ أجْرِيٌ (like in [10:72](http://legacy.quran.com/10/72)), Shoa'ba leaves out the fatha on the yaa' reading it **إنْ أجْرِي**.
- Hafs reads: مِتُّ, مِتُّم and مِتْنا, (see [19:23](http://legacy.quran.com/19/23), [23:82](http://legacy.quran.com/23/82), [23:35](http://legacy.quran.com/23/35) ...) while Sho'aba reads instead **مُتْنا** ,**مُتُّم** and **مُتُّ** with a damah instead of the kasra. Hafs seemed here to be inconsequent.
- Hafs reads in [2:85](http://legacy.quran.com/2/85) عَمَّا تَعْمَلُون while Sho'aba reads it with a yaa' instead of the taa' **عَمَّا يَعْمَلُون**.
- Hafs reads in [2:97](http://legacy.quran.com/2/97) لِجِبْرِيل with a kasra  the jeem while SHoa'ba read it with a fatha **لِجَبْرِيل**.
- In verse [2:98](http://legacy.quran.com/2/98) Hafs reads وَجِبْرِيلَ وٌمِيكَـلَ -as in rasm al-Moshaf- while Sho'aba readboth with hamza **وَجِبْرِئِلَ وٌمِيكَئِـلَ**.

I hope this helps, if you need a transliteration just tell me!

Comment: The link for the osol of this qirat isn’t working.

Comment: Can you kindly update the link of usul ( http://live.islamweb.net/quran_list/shuaba/osol.pdf ). It's not working.

Comment: @RafidAbrar I've added a new link for a download option. I couldn't find that on islamweb actually.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to that answer:

Hafs reads "تَذَكَّرُونَ" while Shu'bah reads "تَذَّكَّرُونَ" with a Tashdid on ذ. This occurs in 24:1, 23:85, 11:30, 11:24, 45:23, 37:155, and so on.